# Why can I not convert this regex return to a string to an integer or straight to an integer? (C++)

Tags: c++, regex, string, char, atoi

I've read a few StackExchange posts and other pages on converting strings to integers, but this is not working. This is the last thing I tried:

```
if (infile.is_open())
{
        while (getline (infile,line))
        {

            regex_match(line,matches,exp);

            regex_match((string)matches[1], time0, exp_time);

            buffer << time0[1];
            str = buffer.str();

            str.append("\0");


            cout << atoi(str.c_str()) << '\n';

            last_match = matches[2];
            buffer.str(string());
        }
        infile.close();
}
```

I can't think of any other ways. I tried the normal convert to string to char * to integer. I tried converting it to a string then using stoi() to convert it to an integer. I tried appending a NULL character ("\0") to it, I tried appending it in the buffer, too. I also tried atof() and stof(). stoi() and stof() both crash the program. atoi() and atof() both return 0, always.

---

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), with the problem featured (`atoi(str.c_str())` should not be 0):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

#include <sstream>

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    regex exp("^(.+),(.+),.+,.+,(.+),.+,.+$");
    regex exp_time("^(.+)-(.+)-(.+)");
    smatch matches;
    smatch time0;
    string line;
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    string last_match;
    stringstream buffer;
    string str;


    int i = 0;

    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(infile, line))
        {

            regex_match(line, matches, exp);

            regex_match((string)matches[1], time0, exp_time);

            buffer << time0[1];
            str = buffer.str();

            str = time0[1].str();
            str.append("\0");



            cout << atoi(str.c_str()) << " " << time0[1] << '\n';

            last_match = matches[2];
            buffer.str(string());
            i++;
        }
        infile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input would be a csv file with these values:

```
1996-09-04,19.00,19.25,18.62,18.87,528000,0.79
1996-09-03,19.00,19.37,18.75,19.00,1012800,0.79
1996-08-30,19.87,20.12,19.37,19.62,913600,0.82
1996-08-29,20.87,21.12,19.75,19.75,1987200,0.82
1996-08-28,20.12,22.12,20.12,21.12,5193600,0.88
1996-08-27,19.75,20.37,19.75,20.12,1897600,0.84
1996-08-26,20.12,20.12,19.75,19.75,388800,0.82
1996-08-23,19.75,20.25,19.75,19.75,1024000,0.82
1996-08-22,18.62,20.00,18.25,19.87,1921600,0.83
1996-08-21,19.12,19.25,18.25,18.62,688000,0.78
1996-08-20,19.62,19.62,19.12,19.12,494400,0.80
1996-08-19,19.37,19.62,19.37,19.62,428800,0.82
1996-08-16,19.50,19.87,19.12,19.37,864000,0.81
```

You would run the program with `program.exe filename.csv`

Here's a shorter program with the problems more apparent:

Comment: what sort of input strings and regexes are you using? are you sure you're getting a string that resembles a number?

Comment: Please write a simple test case showing all definitions

Comment: Have you verified that the regexps actually match and that the second item in the results exists?

Comment: What type do `time0` and `matches` have? Also it is always good to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I added an SSCCE and some example input.

Comment: This is not exactly SSCCE. The program does three things (match a string against a RE, match another string against a different RE, convert yet another string to an integer) and it is never known which of the three operations is at fault. Use your debugger or insert output statements to find out. Isolate and debug that operation. Then, if you still have a problem, build an SSCCE *around that operation alone*. If two or all three operations are working separately but not together, the onus is on you to demonstrate that.

Comment: The part that's at fault is the atoi(). Before that, everything works perfectly. After converting, I get a 0.

Comment: (1) Don't use `atoi(...)`; use `boost::lexical_cast<int>()`;
(2) Don't use C style casts [`(string)`];

Comment: (3) `regex_match` takes the string parameter by constant reference. Casting it creates a temporary that can vanish by the return of the function call;
(4) See this for a small rundown on how to use the str() function on the match type (as well as iterator over the matches) [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/str/); you can use cmatch instead of smatch if you want to use the old style c-strings;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
regex_match((string)matches[1], time0, exp_time);
```

You can't pass a temporary as the subject string of a regex match, because the string contents have to still be around when you query the match results. The result of `(string)matches[1]` is destroyed at the end of the current full expression (i.e. at the next semicolon); when you get around to querying `time0[1]` on the next line, the `time0` match is referring to a string that doesn't exist any more, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It works until the atoi() or the atof(), after that, it changes the match to 0.

Comment: Undefined behaviour doesn't mean it has to crash immediately. It means anything can happen. Reading from a regex match after the subject string has gone away might cause the program to crash, or it might give you garbage, or it might give you the result you expected if the memory hasn't been recycled yet. I can't say what your particular compiler is doing, but my guess is that time0[1] contains garbage, and atoi() is returning 0 because it's not being fed a valid integer.

Comment: Wow, that worked and that sounds like a plausible reason. Very interesting. I didn't know that about temporaries. I'm guessing it's really a return from a function associated with the data type. How do I reward the bounty?

Comment: You left it too late to award the bounty. Half of the bounty was automatically assigned to me because I had the highest rated answer when it expired.

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand it with an example: this is what's happening in my VS2012 environment:

[image]

There's an error in the `buffer << time0[1];` line.

In that line I'm actually calling the [std::ostream::operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) 
by passing it the result of the [std::match_results::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/operator%5B%5D/) which is a **std::sub_match object reference**.

That object can be converted to a `string_type` (an alias of the `basic_string` type being used with the characters being referred by the iterator type) since there's a conversion defined for it.

So I'm doing something:

```
buffer << (string with the contents of sub_match object).
```

At that point **the string must exist and be valid**. A rapid inspection with the debugger shows that something's missing:

[image]

the "*first*" field, which is an **iterator to the beginning of the match**, is missing. That iterator is a [bidirectional iterator pointing to your string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/sub_match/): so **something must have happened to your string**.

If you take a look at how (again, in a VS2012 environment) the *regex_match* function is defined:

```
template<class _StTraits,
    class _StAlloc,
    class _Alloc,
    class _Elem,
    class _RxTraits> inline
    bool regex_match(
        const basic_string<_Elem, _StTraits, _StAlloc>& _Str, <--- take a look here
        match_results<typename basic_string<_Elem, _StTraits, _StAlloc>::
            const_iterator, _Alloc>& _Matches,
        const basic_regex<_Elem, _RxTraits>& _Re,
        regex_constants::match_flag_type _Flgs =
            regex_constants::match_default)
    {   // try to match regular expression to target text
    return (_Regex_match(_Str.begin(), _Str.end(),
        &_Matches, _Re, _Flgs, true));
    }
```

it is clear that is taking a **reference to a const basic_string**, it's **NOT** copying it somehow nor r-value fiddling with it.

You can simulate the same behavior with the following code:

```
std::string::iterator myFirstElement; // every random-access iterator is a bidirectional iterator

void takeAReference(std::string& mystring)
{
  // Here mystring is valid!
  myFirstElement = mystring.begin();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  takeAReference(string("hello dear"));

  // Iterator is now NO MORE VALID! Try to inspect it / use it
  ....
}
```

and try it for yourself. On my machine this won't definitely work and even if it worked you can be sure that sooner or later it will disappoint you.

So that's the reason why you're having weird results. A simple solution could be to just extend your string's scope of visibility:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  regex exp("^(.+),(.+),.+,.+,(.+),.+,.+$");
  regex exp_time("^(.+)-(.+)-(.+)");
  smatch matches;
  smatch time0;
  string line;
  ifstream infile("testfile.txt");
  string last_match;
  stringstream buffer;
  string str;


  int i = 0;

  if (infile.is_open())
  {
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {

      regex_match(line, matches, exp);

      std::string first_date = (string)matches[1]; <--!!

      regex_match(first_date, time0, exp_time);

      buffer << time0[1];
      str = buffer.str();

      str = time0[1].str();
      str.append("\0");

      cout << atoi(str.c_str()) << " " << time0[1] << '\n';

      last_match = matches[2];
      buffer.str(string());
      i++;
    }
    infile.close();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your regex is matching what you want?

for example the regex `"^(.+)-(.+)-(.+)$"` would match the whole line in your example input file, like for example it matches the [whole line](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28.%2b%29,%28.%2b%29,.%2b,.%2b,%28.%2b%29,.%2b,.%2b%24&input=1996-09-04,19.00,19.25,18.62,18.87,528000,0.79%0A1996-09-03,19.00,19.37,18.75,19.00,1012800,0.79%0A1996-08-30,19.87,20.12,19.37,19.62,913600,0.82%0A1996-08-29,20.87,21.12,19.75,19.75,1987200,0.82%0A1996-08-28,20.12,22.12,20.12,21.12,5193600,0.88%0A1996-08-27,19.75,20.37,19.75,20.12,1897600,0.84%0A1996-08-26,20.12,20.12,19.75,19.75,388800,0.82%0A1996-08-23,19.75,20.25,19.75,19.75,1024000,0.82%0A1996-08-22,18.62,20.00,18.25,19.87,1921600,0.83%0A1996-08-21,19.12,19.25,18.25,18.62,688000,0.78%0A1996-08-20,19.62,19.62,19.12,19.12,494400,0.80%0A1996-08-19,19.37,19.62,19.37,19.62,428800,0.82%0A1996-08-16,19.50,19.87,19.12,19.37,864000,0.81):

> 1996-09-04,19.00,19.25,18.62,18.87,528000,0.79

because the `.+` parts will just match anything (incl ,- chars etc.).

So if you want to match just `1996-09-04` then you could try the regex `\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}` or something like that. you can try out the regex in this [online regex-tool](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D-%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D&input=1996-09-04%2C19.00%2C19.25%2C18.62%2C18.87%2C528000%2C0.79%0A1996-09-03%2C19.00%2C19.37%2C18.75%2C19.00%2C1012800%2C0.79%0A1996-08-30%2C19.87%2C20.12%2C19.37%2C19.62%2C913600%2C0.82%0A1996-08-29%2C20.87%2C21.12%2C19.75%2C19.75%2C1987200%2C0.82%0A1996-08-28%2C20.12%2C22.12%2C20.12%2C21.12%2C5193600%2C0.88%0A1996-08-27%2C19.75%2C20.37%2C19.75%2C20.12%2C1897600%2C0.84%0A1996-08-26%2C20.12%2C20.12%2C19.75%2C19.75%2C388800%2C0.82%0A1996-08-23%2C19.75%2C20.25%2C19.75%2C19.75%2C1024000%2C0.82%0A1996-08-22%2C18.62%2C20.00%2C18.25%2C19.87%2C1921600%2C0.83%0A1996-08-21%2C19.12%2C19.25%2C18.25%2C18.62%2C688000%2C0.78%0A1996-08-20%2C19.62%2C19.62%2C19.12%2C19.12%2C494400%2C0.80%0A1996-08-19%2C19.37%2C19.62%2C19.37%2C19.62%2C428800%2C0.82%0A1996-08-16%2C19.50%2C19.87%2C19.12%2C19.37%2C864000%2C0.81)

Also the other regex `^(.+),(.+),.+,.+,(.+),.+,.+$` looks suspicious to me, do really you want to match **any** line that has 6 commas with at least 1 char between them? Remember that the `.` is a very greedy regex.

**UPDATE**: I really think your first regex is too greedy, see [example here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28.%2b%29,%28.%2b%29,.%2b,.%2b,%28.%2b%29,.%2b,.%2b%24&input=1996-09-04,19.00,19.25,18.62,18.87,528000,0.79%0A1996-09-03,19.00,19.37,18.75,19.00,1012800,0.79%0A1996-08-30,19.87,20.12,19.37,19.62,913600,0.82%0A1996-08-29,20.87,21.12,19.75,19.75,1987200,0.82%0A1996-08-28,20.12,22.12,20.12,21.12,5193600,0.88%0A1996-08-27,19.75,20.37,19.75,20.12,1897600,0.84%0A1996-08-26,20.12,20.12,19.75,19.75,388800,0.82%0A1996-08-23,19.75,20.25,19.75,19.75,1024000,0.82%0A%20%20%20%20%20%201996-08-22,18.62,20.00,18.25,19.87,1921600,0.83take%20a%20look%20what%20your%20regex%20matches%20here!%20.4345243m45,.%E1%B8%89%60%2b%2b%2b%C3%A7------%20%20ble%20bla%20bla%0A1996-08-21,19.12,19.25,18.25,18.62,688000,0.78%0A1996-08-20,19.62,19.62,19.12,19.12,494400,0.80%0A1996-08-19,19.37,19.62,19.37,19.62,428800,0.82%0A1996-08-16,19.50,19.87,19.12,19.37,864000,0.81)

Comment: Yes, regex is matching everything perfectly. The code is all perfect until the `atoi()` at `cout << atoi(str.c_str()) << " " << time0[1] << '\n';`

Comment: @JVE999 donfuxx is correct, the regex isn't really doing what you think it's doing. It happens to work on your input, but if you replaced it with bogus input (eg, `-----`), the regex would still match, and you would get a 0 when you try to parse with `atoi` _without any indication of an error_. Also, the `.` isn't the only thing that's greedy--the `+` is also. So if the input was `foo-bar-biz-baz`, a match would still happen, and one of the matches will contain a `-` in it.

Comment: I couldn't think of a better way to do it at the time. Now, I've found `([^,]+)` or `([^-]+)` is much simpler, and `([^,]*)` and `([^-]*)` might make it more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

`int atoi (const char * str);`

Try using a char array instead of a `string`.

Comment: `string::c_str` returns a `char *`

Comment: Good point!  I looked everywhere before the actual atoi call.  Woops!

Answer (score -1):

I think the KISS principle can be applied here to get a better solution than using regex. Simply read in each field using `istream`. *Regex is overkill* IMHO.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct date_t
{
  int year, month, day;
};

struct data_t
{
  date_t date;
  float f1, f2, f3, f4;
  int i;
  float f5;
};

istream & operator>>(istream & in, date_t &date)
{
  char d1, d2;  // dummy chars for the hyphens
  return in >> date.year >> d1 >> date.month >> d2 >> date.day;
}

istream & operator>>(istream & in, data_t &data)
{
  char d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6;  // dummy chars for the commas
  return in >> data.date >> d1 >> data.f1 >> d2 >> data.f2 >> d3
    >> data.f3 >> d4 >> data.f4 >> d5 >> data.i >> d6 >> data.f5;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const date_t &date)
{
  return out << date.year << '-' << date.month << '-' << date.day;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const data_t &data)
{
  return out << data.date << ',' << data.f1 << ',' << data.f2 << ','
    << data.f3 << ',' << data.f4 << ',' << data.i << ',' << data.f5;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ifstream infile(argv[1]);

  data_t data;
  while(infile >> data) {
    cout << "Here is the data: " << data << endl;
  }

  infile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Heck, `iostream` is kind of overkill too. Here is a C solution using `fscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct date_t
{
  int year, month, day;
};

struct data_t
{
  struct date_t date;
  float f1, f2, f3, f4;
  int i;
  float f5;
};

int read_data(FILE *fid, struct data_t *data)
{
  return fscanf(fid, "%d-%d-%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%d,%f",
      &(data->date.year), &(data->date.month), &(data->date.day),
      &(data->f1), &(data->f2), &(data->f3), &(data->f4), &(data->i), &(data->f5));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rt");

  struct data_t data;

  while(read_data(fp, &data) == 9) {
    printf("Here is your data: %d-%02d-%02d,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%d,%.2f\n",
      data.date.year, data.date.month, data.date.day,
      data.f1, data.f2, data.f3, data.f4, data.i, data.f5);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

See how much shorter and easy to understand that is? The `scanf` format specifier can *easily* capture the format of your data, and it's much simpler to use than regex. Note that you don't have to split the data into tokens, and then parse each token. You get the parsed, numeric output right away.

Comment: Note the scanf version is actually doing more than the C++ version. The scanf will actually check the delimiters (hyphens/comma),. whereas the C++ version will accept all sorts of invalid data without complaint.